# ethtool: set/unset autonegation, RX/TX pause

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ethernet

I was looking at the sources of `ethtool`, particularly at function `do_spause()` where autonegotiation, rx/tx pause can be enabled/disabled. I noticed that at first it issues `ioctl()` for `ETHTOOL_GPAUSEPARAM` command, i.e. it fetches the current settings, and they're the same, it doesn't change anything, otherwise it will issue `ioctl()` with `ETHTOOL_SPAUSEPARAM` command and set new parameters.

What is the reason for this? Is this optimization, or way to avoid link disruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ethtool_ops are implemented separately for each device type.  It would be reckless to assume all ioctls are benign when setting an already set value.  Implementation in the kernel is here:

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/net/core/ethtool.c#L1003

Comment: thanks for comment. Is this also true for offload features setting? (Read the current offload settings,and if a flag already set, don't try to do this.)

Comment: Changing offload seems as likely to cause disruption as other params.